# How to increase amount resolution of data exported as ER model using data modeler in sql developer - Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I exported a ER model in oracle's sql developer but the image exported is very low resolution. Is there anyway i can improve it?

[image]

I want to increase the exported diagram quality from sql developer.

SQL Developer info
version 23.1.0.097
Build 097.1607

Answer (score 0):

File -> Print Diagram -> SVG

Here's my diagram, blown up to 200% in Chrome, note the sharpness.

[image]